# Single thread pool - ExecutorService or Handler + HandlerThread

Tags: android, multithreading

Traditionally, when I need a single thread pool, I will use

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.submit(...
```

However, when look at [Weather List Widget](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/src/com/example/android/weatherlistwidget/WeatherWidgetProvider.html), I realize that we can use `Handler` + `HandlerThread` to achieve the similar objective

```
HandlerThread sWorkerThread = new HandlerThread("WeatherWidgetProvider-worker");
sWorkerThread.start();
Handler sWorkerQueue = new Handler(sWorkerThread.getLooper());
sWorkerQueue.post(...
```

I was wondering, what is the consideration I should take, in order have a right choice among them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HandlerThread is simpler than than ExecutorService. So it will use less resources and work faster. So if you have a lot of small messages process them via Handler.

But Executors it's not just a class. Executors is a standart. It's a framework with a lot of features and every java programmer can understand your code written with executors. A lot of libraries can work with executors. It's flexible, you can easily change executor type or executor queue. So if you have a complex processing task and you do not know how exactly implement it use executors.